# Can a Spring Boot application be terminated within code when Tomcat server cannot start?

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot

When I launch my Spring Boot application while the Tomcat's port is already in use, I can see in a log file that java.net.BindException (Address already in use) is thrown, but the application still continues to run (the Java process is still up).
Is there any way that I can terminate the application within its code when the Tomcat server fails to start?

Comment: You could listen tomcat events and stop java process when tomcat throws an error.